# How to load an unmanaged DLL from a stream?

Tags: .net, vb.net, pinvoke, unmanaged

I have an application written in .NET 4.0 that needs to load in memory a native DLL (written C).

At the moment I am using a P/Invoke call to LoadLibrary passing the path where the DLL is located.

This works, but due to the fact that this DLL comes from a DB, I would like to know if it is possible loading it through a stream, avoiding then the necessity to store the DLL somewhere in the filesystem.

Comment: You can do it in native apps, so in theory you could rewrite that in .NET https://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/loading-a-dll-from-memory/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows does not permit this, native code must always be loaded from a file on disk.  This is core to the way the operating system was designed, executables are mapped into memory through a memory-mapped file.  Which requires a file.

It works for pure managed code (Assembly.Load(byte[]) only because IL is data, not native code.

Avoid storing DLLs in a dbase, you cannot normally write them to disk since either UAC or the virus scanner or IT staff is quite unhappy about executables files appearing from nowhere.  It will work on your dev machine but odds are quite low on the user's machine.

Comment: The application is quite complex and it has been designed to work in specific environment. Thank you for the information, I would proceed extracting to filesystem then.

Comment: This is false. You can load a DLL from memory, and this is called Manual Mapping.

Comment: Felix, can you please explain how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible because you specify the file name in your PInvoke attribute usages. PInvoke needs a file name which is statically known.

If you can't decide on the file name statically, you might need to use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to call the functions contained in the dll.

Or you can use reflection emit to dynamically emit PInvoke functions.

Comment: Do exist other API other than LoadLibrary that could be used to load a DLL in memory from a stream?

Comment: No such API exists. Many Windows APIs and likely the kernel, too, expect a loaded library to be based on a memory-mapped file.